# Swift decode json error: keyNotFound

Tags: json, swift

```
{
"coord": {
    "lon": -122.03,
    "lat": 37.33
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 701,
        "main": "Mist",
        "description": "mist",
        "icon": "50n"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 287.01,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 77,
    "temp_min": 282.15,
    "temp_max": 290.15
},
"visibility": 16093,
"wind": {
    "speed": 1.5,
    "deg": 290
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 1
},
"dt": 1528023600,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 428,
    "message": 0.0042,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1528030097,
    "sunset": 1528082688
},
"id": 5341145,
"name": "Cupertino",
"cod": 200
}
```

I try to decode this to my object use following codes:

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let object = try decoder.decode(Object.self, from: data)
    return object
} catch {
    print("JSON Error: \(error)")
    return Object(weather: Weather(), main: Main())
}
```

And this my object:

```
struct Object: Codable {
    var weather: Weather
    var main: Main
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    var city = ""
    var description = ""
    var icon = ""

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case city = "name"
        case description = "main"
        case icon
    }
}

struct Main: Codable {
    var temputure = ""

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temputure = "temp"
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

> JSON Error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "weather", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode
>   Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError:
>   nil))

I want to know how to fix this.

Comment: Well the description of the error says it: `Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead`. Your `weather` key is not an object but rather an array of objects.

Comment: @MihaiFratu How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CodingKeys(stringValue: "weather", intValue: nil)], debugDescription:
>   "**Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead**

From Debug This error you have  `Weather` is an Array `[]`  not dictionary `{}`

At Json  `[]`  is Array and `{}` is Dictionary

**Model:**

```
    struct Object: Codable {
        let weather: [Weather]
        let main: Main
    }
    struct Main: Codable {
        let temp: Double
        let pressure, humidity: Int
        let tempMin, tempMax: Double

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case temp, pressure, humidity
            case tempMin = "temp_min"
            case tempMax = "temp_max"
        }
    }
    struct Weather: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let main, description, icon: String
    }
```

**Use it :**

```
    do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let object = try decoder.decode(Object.self, from: data)
    return object
}  
    catch {
    print("JSON Error: \(error)")
    return Object(weather: Weather(), main: Main())
}
```